# How to query a linked list with T-Sql to find the Root Node

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-list

I am trying to find out from my SQL Server 2012 table what the root `WorldID` is from data that has a parent child relationship (yes, this is for a role playing game system).

The data sample is this:

[image: The Data]

The query I used to show the the data is:

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Name
    ,WorldID_Orig
    ,WorldID_From
    ,(Select Name from REF_World WHERE ID = WorldID_From) as 'WorldFrom_Name'
    ,WorldID_To
    ,(Select Name from REF_World WHERE ID = WorldID_To) as 'WorldTo_Name'
    ,ObjectType
    ,ObjID_From
    ,ObjID_To
    ,(Select Name from REF_Armor WHERE ID = ObjID_To) as 'Obj_Name'
    ,DateImported 
FROM 
    REF_WorldObjectTrading   
WHERE 
    ID > 3625
    AND ObjectType = 'REF_Armor'
    AND (Select Name from REF_Armor WHERE ID = ObjID_To) = 'Body: Dimension Shift' 
ORDER BY 
    WorldID_From, ObjID_From
```

This data is representative of the data I have in my table. What I would like to do is for each row populate the `WorldID_Orig` with whatever `WorldID_From` is the first one in the chain. In this case that would be WorldID = 1.

What I'm struggling with is how to find that the root `WorldID` is 1 from the data if I have the data from, say, the 4th row of results here. I believe it will involve something along these lines ... but I'm not quite getting how to find the root ID.

```
declare @ParentID int
set @ParentID= 41385 --(select ID 
                        from REF_Armor 
                        where Name = 'Body: Dimension Shift')

;WITH T (Name, WorldFrom, WorldTo, WorldToName, ObjFrom, ObjTo) AS
( 
    SELECT 
        Name, WorldID_From, WorldID_To, 
        (SELECT Name FROM REF_World WHERE ID = WorldID_To) as WorldToName, 
        ObjID_From, ObjID_To 
    FROM 
        REF_WorldObjectTrading 
    WHERE 
        ObjID_From = @ParentID
        AND ObjectType = 'REF_Armor'
        AND ID > 3625

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        T1.name, T1.WorldID_From, T1.WorldID_To, 
        (SELECT Name FROM REF_World WHERE ID = WorldID_To) as WorldToName, 
        t1.ObjID_From, t1.ObjID_To
    FROM 
        REF_WorldObjectTrading T1 
    INNER JOIN 
        T ON T1.objID_From = T.ObjFrom
    WHERE 
        T.ObjFrom <> @ParentID
)
select * 
from T
order by objTo, WorldFrom
```

If anyone can help me to nail this down, I'd be very appreciative. I feel I'm close, but I'm just not getting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was two fold.  First I needed to make sure that when new Things (such as a new Armor in the REF_Armor table) are added that a new row is added to the Tracing table that has the ParentID NULL.  That is done as follows:

```
    Dim WorldID_Orig As Integer = MySession.World.ID
    Dim Name As String = "Create " & Session("NewItemName")
    Dim ObjID_From As Integer = Nothing
    Dim ObjectID As Integer = NewItemID
    Dim ObjectType As String = "REF_Armor"
    Dim WorldID_From As Integer = Nothing
    Dim WorldID_To As Integer = Nothing

    MySession.EC.WOT_Insert(WorldID_Orig, Name, ObjID_From, ObjectID, ObjectType, WorldID_From, WorldID_To)
```

This occurs in the following event:

```
 Protected Sub dsDataView_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles dsDataView.Inserted
```

The WOT_Insert procedure does the following:

```
    Public Sub WOT_Insert(WorldID_Orig As Integer,
                          Name As String,
                          ObjID_From As Integer,
                          ObjectID As Integer,
                          ObjectType As String,
                          WorldID_From As Integer,
                          WorldID_To As Integer)

        Dim wot As New Elthos_ODS.WorldObjectTrading
        wot.WorldID_Orig = WorldID_Orig  ' -- HERE WE NEED TO QUERY THE DATABASE TO FIND THE ORIGINAL WORLD ID
        wot.DateImported = Now
        wot.DateModified = Nothing
        wot.DateRemoved = Nothing
        wot.Name = Name
        wot.ObjID_From = ObjID_From
        wot.ObjectID = ObjectID
        wot.ObjectType = ObjectType
        wot.WorldID_From = WorldID_From
        wot.WorldID_To = WorldID_To
        wot.InsertClassToDB()

    End Sub
```

Lastly the SQL that queries the database is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[S_SYS_Admin_WOT_Trace] (
    @ObjectID as int,
    @ObjectType as varchar(255)
)

AS 

;WITH Hierarchy (
        WorldID_Orig,
        Name,
        WorldID_From,
        WorldID_To,
        ObjID_From, 
        ObjectID, 
        Parents)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        WorldID_Orig,
        Name,
        WorldID_From,
        WorldID_To,
        ObjID_From, 
        ObjectID, 
        CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM REF_WorldObjectTrading AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE 
        WorldID_From = 0 
        and WorldID_To = 0 
        and ObjectType = @ObjectType
        and ID > 3625
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      nextgeneration.WorldID_Orig,
      NextGeneration.Name, 
      NextGeneration.WorldID_From, 
      NextGeneration.WorldID_To, 
      nextgeneration.ObjID_From, 
      NextGeneration.objectID, 
        CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
            THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.ObjID_From AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
            ELSE(Parent.Parents + '.' + CAST(NextGeneration.ObjID_From AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM REF_WorldObjectTrading AS NextGeneration
     INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent 
        ON NextGeneration.objID_From = Parent.ObjectID
        WHERE Parent.ObjectID <> @ObjectID
)
SELECT *
    FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

I hope this helps others who may find themselves in a similar situation.